# NoMethodError on has_many relationship ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, relationships

I have three models and i am trying to get the persons in the respective teams associated with the products.

Product

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
   mount_uploader :photo, ImageUploader
   has_one :team
end
```

Team

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :persons
 belongs_to :product
end
```

Person

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
 mount_uploader :photo, ImageUploader
 belongs_to :team
end
```

When i try this call

```
@product = Product.find_by(name: params[:name])
if @product.team.count > 0
  @team = @product.team.persons
end
```

I get

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `count' for #<Team:0x90dc098>):
```

Comment: changed it to where now NoMethodError (undefined method `team' for #<Product::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x4a97c18>):

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> NoMethodError (undefined method `count' for Team:0x90dc098)

`count` works on array of `ActiveRecord::Relation`. Here `find_by` returns a single record not a `ActiveRecord::Relation`. Changing `find_by` to `where` should work.

```
@product = Product.where(name: params[:name]).first
if @product.team.count > 0
  @team = @product.team.persons
end
```

Comment: now there is this NoMethodError (undefined method `team' for #<Product::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x4a97c18>):

Comment: Good work `@Pavan` - nice knowledge of the underlying ruby functionality

Answer (score 1):

The count function you are applying to is not an array, hence you would receive that error. You could do this:

```
@product = Product.find_by(name: params[:name])

if @product.team.present? 
  @team = @product.team.persons 
end
```

Or use a where clause mentioned by Pavan

Answer (score 1):

Just to add something extra ([`.try`](http://everydayrails.com/2011/04/28/rails-try-method.html)):

```
@product = Product.find_by name: params[:name]
@team    = @product.try(:team).try(:persons) #-> returns false if team or persons nil
```

You'd then use some conditional logic in the front-end:

```
<% if @team %>
```

... which is basically the same pattern you have now.